# Problems in MySQL connection for Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have taken a php script from the web server as JSON Array. I want to view the data from the list view as in this tutorial in Android Hive  [enter link description here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

First the app went not responding but now it is working but not populating in the list view.

This is my Code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Event extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventList;


    private static String url_all_events = "http://examplesite.lk/sports/data.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_EVENTS = "events";
    private static final String TAG_SID = "sportsid";
    private static final String TAG_VS = "vs";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
    private static final String TAG_VENUE = "venue";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray events = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_events);


        eventList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        new LoadAllEvents().execute();


    }

    class LoadAllEvents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Event.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading events. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_events, "GET", params);


            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {

                events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String sid = c.getString(TAG_SID);
                    String vs = c.getString(TAG_VS);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    String venue = c.getString(TAG_VENUE);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_SID, sid);
                    map.put(TAG_VS, vs);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                    map.put(TAG_VENUE, venue);



                    eventList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            pDialog.dismiss();


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Event.this, eventList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_VS,
                                    TAG_DATE},
                                    new int[] { R.id.opponent, R.id.time });

                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```

the main list view is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the list item layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/borders"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opponent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/school"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The Json Array is

```
{"events":[{"id":"2","sportid":"1","vs":"CollegeA","date":"2014-05-02 17:30:00","venue":"Grounds"},{"id":"1","sportid":"1","vs":"CollegeB","date":"2014-04-17 17:30:00","venue":"Grounds"}]}
```

Can anyone tell me where i went wrong. and why the data is not produced in the list view

Comment: any error you are getting on logcat???

Comment: 04-11 15:52:17.828: E/AndroidRuntime(24140): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.Event}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: put your full activity code it means how you write an listview with findviewbyid.

Comment: seems like you do not use `the main list view` in your ListFragment at all coud you share with us your `onCreateView` method of your `ListFragment` derived class (or `onCreate` of `ListActivity`)?

Comment: @Selvin I edited the question with the full activity class

Comment: ok now are you sure that layout `all_events.xml` is "`the main list view`"

Comment: @Selvin yes its the main list view. where i need to show the data. So once the activity is selected it will use all_events.xml to show the data. but i dont know whether all_events.xml or list_item.xml is wrong

Comment: @Ruch..can you check by writing this line..
        ListView lv = getListView(); in oncreate();

Comment: you cant get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'` if you have `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list">` in main layout ... try to rebuild the project and check the logcat again ... try to comment `setContentView(R.layout.all_events);` to check if it works at all

Comment: @Nil.. Then the lv is unused. so where to use lv ?

Comment: @Nil.. Now everything is working fine but the thing is. the main layout wont show the data in it.

Answer (score 0):

I got to know the error. There was some errors in my server and some syntax errors. Anyway Thanks guys.
Just had to add this code to work

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```